# How to get match array index from given ranges array with min max values

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get matched javascript array index as I expected ?
Range min - First value
Range max - Last value of the given array

```
var arr = [{
    range:[0,20],
    title:"First"
    data:["a","b"]
},
{
    range:[20,40],
    title:"Second"
    data:["d","f"]
},
{
    range:[40,60],
    title:"THird"
    data:["g","k"]
}];


function getRange( value ){
    // retun index of the array
}

getRange( 22 ) -> Expect to get 1 as the array index
getRange( 50 ) -> Expect to get 2 as the array index
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read the ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527)

Comment: Also, your ranges overlap. What should be the returned index when I pass `20`?

Comment: People are probably downvoting this because of a lack of effort.  I know there are answers below; still, could you show us some of what you tried yourself?

Comment: Also, do you really want to find the index?  Or are you only using that to then select the object that contains the range?  If that's the case, then a better function would return that object directly, or even a single property from it if that's what you need to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```js
var arr = [{range:[0,20],title:"First",data:["a","b"]},{range:[20,40],title:"Second",data:["d","f"]},{range:[40,60],title:"THird",data:["g","k"]}];

function getRange( value ){
    return arr.findIndex(v => value >= v.range[0] && value <= v.range[1]);
}

console.log(getRange(22));
console.log(getRange(50));
```

**Note**: As the function counts the range to be **inclusive** of low and high values, in case of boundary values **(20, 40, etc)**, index of first match will be returned. e.g. in case of 40, index returned will be 1.

Answer (score 1):

1) Note there are a couple of missing commas separating the properties in your data.

2) You need to update your range patterns (0-20, 21-40 etc) to ensure you don't run into problems later.

3) You can use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to return the index of the *first* object where the value is within the range.

```js
var arr = [{"range":[0,20],"title":"First","data":["a","b"]},{"range":[21,40],"title":"Second","data":["d","f"]},{"range":[41,60],"title":"THird","data":["g","k"]}];

function getRange(arr, value){

  // for each object in the array get the range property
  return arr.findIndex(({ range }) => {
  
    // and return the first index where the value
    // fits within the range
    return value >= range[0] && value <= range[1];
  });
}

console.log(getRange(arr, 22));
console.log(getRange(arr, 50));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through all array items in order to compare if the value is available within array values range. You can do it through 'for' loop in JS.

Below is the code sample and give a try and play around it:

```
var arr = [{
    range:[0,20],
    title:"First"
    data:["a","b"]
},
{
    range:[20,40],
    title:"Second"
    data:["d","f"]
},
{
    range:[40,60],
    title:"THird"
    data:["g","k"]
}];


function getRange( value ){
    // retun index of the array
 for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
   if(value > arr[i][0] && value <= arr[i][1]){
      return arr[i];
   } else{
    return null;
   }
 }
}
```

Note: Here if the value is "20", then it will return the first array item. Just because we are comparing "<=" in if condition. It doesn't select second array item in your case.

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.

Answer (score 0):

loop over the array and in each range check if the value lies between the values in range.

It may happen that the value is in the range which are in two different index. So it keep an array and push all the index in it

```js
var arr = [{
    range: [0, 20],
    title: "First",
    data: ["a", "b"]
  },
  {
    range: [20, 40],
    title: "Second",
    data: ["d", "f"]
  },
  {
    range: [40, 60],
    title: "THird",
    data: ["g", "k"]
  }
];


function getRange(value) {
  let inxArray = [];
  arr.forEach(function(item, index) {
    if (value >= item.range[0] && value <= item.range[1]) {
      inxArray.push(index)
    }


  });
  return inxArray
}

console.log(getRange(22)[0])
console.log(getRange(50)[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.findIndex()` method:

```js
var arr = [{
    range:[0,20],
    title:"First",
    data:["a","b"]
},
{
    range:[20,40],
    title:"Second",
    data:["d","f"]
},
{
    range:[40,60],
    title:"THird",
    data:["g","k"]
}];


function getRange( value ){
   var index = arr.findIndex(obj => obj.range[0] < value && value < obj.range[1]);
   return index;
}

console.log(getRange( 22 ));
console.log(getRange( 50 ));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using es6

```
function getRange( value ){
  return arr.findIndex(item=>{
    if(value>item.range[0] && value<=item.range[1]){
      return true;
    }
  });
}
```

If you are not using es6

```
function getRange( value ){
  var flag = -1; 
  arr.map((item, i)=>{
    if(value>item.range[0] && value<=item.range[1]){
      flag = i;
    }
  });
  return flag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [{
    range:[0,20],
    title:"First",
    data:["a","b"]
},
{
    range:[20,40],
    title:"Second",
    data:["d","f"]
},
{
    range:[40,60],
    title:"THird",
    data:["g","k"]
}];


function getRange( value ){
    arr.map(a=>
    console.log((a.range[0]<=value && a.range[1]>=value)? arr.indexOf(a):'')
    );
}

getRange( 22 )// Expect to get 1 as the array index
getRange( 50 ) // Expect to get 2 as the array index
```

Iterate over the array and check the range in between ranges array then return index.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want `getRange(value)` to return the item's index where `item.range[0] < value && item.range[1] > value`.

Because of the way the object is structured, there's nothing in the code to prevent 2 items from having overlapping ranges. In that case, would you want to return the first match, the last match, or some other result? For instance, what would you expect if you called `getRange(20)` in this example.

Also, your example has some missing commas after the "title" properties.

Ignoring all that, you could use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for a nice terse solution.

```
function getRange(value) {
    return arr.reduce(function(result, item, i) {
        if (result === null) {
            result = item.range[0] <= value && item.range[1] > value ? i : result;
        }
        return result;
    }, null);
}
```